# automatic detection of matrix size, numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I created a code that adds a value of 10 in each column. But it's only created for an array that has 3 rows.
I have more matrix in a cycle with different dimensions
Is it possible to do this so that I don't have to constantly forward the number of columns or rows, but to do so it automatically finds out the number of columns?

```
import numpy as np
c1=np.array([[1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3], [4,4,4]])
#c2=np.array([[1,1,1,1], [2,2,2,2], [3,3,3,3], [4,4,4,4]])
#c3=np.array([[1,1,1,1], [2,2,2,2], [3,3,3,3]])
left=c1+10*np.ones((4,1))*((1,2,3,))#*p
print('\n')
print(left)
#p +=1
```

example

```
left=c1+10*np.ones((4,1))*((1,2,3,)) #4 rows and 3 columns
left=c1+10*np.ones((3,1))*((1,2,3,4)) #3 rows and 4 columns
```

output:

```
array([[11., 21., 31.],
       [12., 22., 32.],
       [13., 23., 33.],
       [14., 24., 34.]])
```

Comment: `numpy` arrays have a `shape` parameter.  Learn what it means.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the multiple of tens to be added to be proportional to the column number (as in your answer), you can make a `range` based on the number of columns and multiply by 10:

```
>>> np.arange(1, c1.shape[1]+1)*10

array([10, 20, 30])

>>> c1 + np.arange(1, c1.shape[1]+1)*10

array([[11, 21, 31],
       [12, 22, 32],
       [13, 23, 33],
       [14, 24, 34]])

>>> c2 + np.arange(1, c2.shape[1]+1)*10 # same but with c2

array([[11, 21, 31, 41],
       [12, 22, 32, 42],
       [13, 23, 33, 43],
       [14, 24, 34, 44]])
```

Your description OTOH makes it sound like you want to just add `10` to every element, in which case it is as simple as `c1 + 10`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `c1.shape[1]` to get the size along the second dimension (i.e. the number of columns), then `np.arange` to create an array of matching size filled with the numbers 0, 1, 2, and so on:

```
>>> c1.shape
(4, 3)
>>> np.arange(5)
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> c1 + 10 * (np.arange(c1.shape[1]) + 1)
array([[11, 21, 31],
       [12, 22, 32],
       [13, 23, 33],
       [14, 24, 34]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
import numpy as np
c1=np.array([[1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3], [4,4,4]])
#c2=np.array([[1,1,1,1], [2,2,2,2], [3,3,3,3], [4,4,4,4]])
#c3=np.array([[1,1,1,1], [2,2,2,2], [3,3,3,3]])
left=c1+10*np.ones(c1.shape)#*p
print('\n')
print(left)
```

The .shape parameter in numpy returns the shape of the array. [docs](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.shape.html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe numpy is way more efficient than you think. If you wish to add or multiply a scalar you don't have to give size. you can directly perform operation.

```
c1=np.array([[1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3], [4,4,4]])
c1 = c1 + 10
```

To answer you question you can use shape which returns shape.

```
dim_tuple = c1.shape
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the shape of your matrix :

```
r, c = c1.shape
```

and then you calculate the matrix you want to add this way :

```
np.ones((r,c))*([i+1 for i in range(c)])
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
c1=np.array([[1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3], [4,4,4]])
#c2=np.array([[1,1,1,1], [2,2,2,2], [3,3,3,3], [4,4,4,4]])
#c3=np.array([[1,1,1,1], [2,2,2,2], [3,3,3,3]])
r, c = c1.shape
left=c1+np.ones((r,c))*([i+1 for i in range(c)])#*p
print('\n')
print(left)
#p +=1
```

Output :

```
array([[11., 21., 31.],
       [12., 22., 32.],
       [13., 23., 33.],
       [14., 24., 34.]])
```